# Apache Spark SQL UDAF over window showing odd behaviour with duplicate input

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have found that in Apache Spark SQL (version 2.2.0), when a user-defined aggregate function (UDAF) that is used over a window specification is supplied with multiple rows of identical input, the UDAF does (seemingly) not call the `evaluate` method correctly.

I have been able to reproduce this behavior both in Java and Scala, locally and on a cluster. The code below shows an example where rows are marked as false if they are within 1 second of the previous row.

```
class ExampleUDAF(val timeLimit: Long) extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  def deterministic: Boolean = true
  def inputSchema: StructType = StructType(Array(StructField("unix_time", LongType)))
  def dataType: DataType = BooleanType

  def bufferSchema = StructType(Array(
    StructField("previousKeepTime", LongType),
    StructField("keepRow", BooleanType)
  ))

  def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
    buffer(0) = 0L
    buffer(1) = false
  }

  def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = {    
    if (buffer(0) == 0L) {
      buffer(0) = input.getLong(0)
      buffer(1) = true
    } else {
      val timeDiff = input.getLong(0) - buffer.getLong(0)

      if (timeDiff < timeLimit) {
        buffer(1) = false
      } else {
        buffer(0) = input.getLong(0)
        buffer(1) = true
      }
    }
  }

  def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row) = {} // Not implemented
  def evaluate(buffer: Row): Boolean = buffer.getBoolean(1)
 }

val timeLimit = 1000 // 1 second
val udaf = new ExampleUDAF(timeLimit)

val window = Window
  .orderBy(column("unix_time"))
  .partitionBy(column("category"))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Arrays.asList(
    Row(1510000001000L, "a", true), 
    Row(1510000001000L, "a", false), 
    Row(1510000001000L, "a", false),
    Row(1510000001000L, "a", false),
    Row(1510000700000L, "a", true),
    Row(1510000700000L, "a", false)
  ), new StructType().add("unix_time", LongType).add("category", StringType).add("expected_result", BooleanType))

df.withColumn("actual_result", udaf(column("unix_time")).over(window)).show
```

Below is the output of running the code above. The first row is expected to have a `actual_result` value of true, as there is no prior data. When the `unix_time` input is modified to have 1 millisecond between each record, the UDAF works as expected.

Adding print statements in the UDAF methods revealed that `evaluate` is only called once, at the end, and that buffer was correctly updated to true in the `update` method, but this is not what is returned after the completion of the UDAF.

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|    unix_time|category|expected_result|actual_result|
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|1510000001000|       a|           true|        false|  // Should true as first element
|1510000001000|       a|          false|        false|
|1510000001000|       a|          false|        false|
|1510000001000|       a|          false|        false|
|1510000700000|       a|           true|        false|  // Should be true as more than 1000 milliseconds between self and previous
|1510000700000|       a|          false|        false|
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

I am understanding Spark's UDAF behavior correctly when used over window specifications?  If not, could anyone offer any insight in this area. If my understanding of UDAF behaviour over windows is correct, could this be a bug in Spark? Thank you.

Comment: A workaround to this problem is to ensure that all input into Spark UDAFs are unique i.e. there are no duplicates

Comment: another workaround is the first calculate `row_number` (ordered by unix_time), then use this `row_number` as ordering column in your window-specification instead of `unix_time`. It seems like the problem is the the order is not clearly defined

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One problem with your UDAF is that it does not specify on which rows you want to run your window with `rowsBetween()`. If there is no `rowsBetween()` specification,  for each row the window function will take **all** (**See update below**) rows before and after current one including current one (in given category). So the `actual_result` for all rows will basically take into account only two last rows in your example `DataFrame`, with `unix_time=1510000700000` which effectively will return `false` for all rows.

With a `window` declaration like this:

```
Window.partitionBy(col("category")).orderBy(col("unix_time")).rowsBetween(-1L, 0L)
```

You are always looking only on previous row and current row. With previous row taken first. This creates correct output. But since the ordering of rows with the same `unix_time` is not unique, it is not possible to predict which row will have value `true` among rows with identical `unix_time`.

The result could look like this:

```
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|    unix_time|category|expected_result|actual_result|
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
|1510000001000|       a|          false|         true|
|1510000001000|       a|          false|        false|
|1510000001000|       a|          false|        false|
|1510000001000|       a|           true|        false|
|1510000700000|       a|           true|         true|
|1510000700000|       a|          false|        false|
+-------------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

**Update**

After investigating further, it seems that when `orderBy` column is provided it takes all elements before current row + current row. Not all elements of partition like I said before. In addition, if orderBy column
contains duplicate values window for each duplicated row will contain all duplicated values. You can see it clearly by doing:

```
val wA = Window.partitionBy(col("category")).orderBy(col("unix_time"))
val wB = Window.partitionBy(col("category"))
val wC = Window.partitionBy(col("category")).orderBy(col("unix_time")).rowsBetween(-1L, 0L)

df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wA)).show()
df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wB)).show()
df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wC)).show()
```

which will count number of elements in each window.

- Window `wA` will have 4 elements in each 1510000001000 row and 6 elements for every 1510000700000.
- For `wB` when there is no `orderBy` all rows are included in the window for each partition, so all windows will have 6 elements.
- The last `wC` specifies the selection of rows, so does not leave ambiguity which rows are selected for which window. There is only 1 element for first row and 2 elements in windows of all subsequent rows. Which produces correct result.

I learned something new today too :)

Comment: can you explain why  `df.withColumn("rnb",row_number().over(Window.orderBy($"unix_time"))).withColumn("actual_result", udaf($"unix_time").over(Window.orderBy($"rnb"))).show` gives the expected result?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth Good question. Try these three windows  `val wA = Window.partitionBy(col("category")).orderBy(col("unix_time"))`
`val wB = Window.partitionBy(col("category"))`
`val wC = Window.partitionBy(col("category")).orderBy(col("unix_time")).rowsBetween(-1L, 0L)` with `df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wA)).show()`
`df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wB)).show()`
`df.withColumn("countRows", count(col("unix_time")).over(wC)).show()`.

Comment: @RaphaelRoth It seems that if there are non unique values in `orderBy` column it puts them all in the window for each non unique row. I had no Idea! Good to know! Also if there is no orderBy, it will take all values for given category. If orderBy is specified it takes all rows before. Also good to know. I will update my answer! But still supplying `.rowsBetween(-1L, 0L)` does the trick in just one passage through data!