# how to use spark sql udaf to implement window counting with condition?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a table with columns: timestamp and id and condition, and I want to count the number of each id per interval such as 10 seconds.

If condition is true, the count++， otherwise return the previous value.

the udaf code like:

```java
public class MyCount extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {

    @Override
    public StructType inputSchema() {
        return DataTypes.createStructType(
                Arrays.asList(
                        DataTypes.createStructField("condition", DataTypes.BooleanType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.LongType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("interval", DataTypes.IntegerType, true)
                )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public StructType bufferSchema() {
        return DataTypes.createStructType(
                Arrays.asList(
                        DataTypes.createStructField("timestamp", DataTypes.LongType, true),
                        DataTypes.createStructField("count", DataTypes.LongType, true)
                )
        );
    }

    @Override
    public DataType dataType() {
        return DataTypes.LongType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deterministic() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(MutableAggregationBuffer mutableAggregationBuffer) {
        mutableAggregationBuffer.update(0, 0L);
        mutableAggregationBuffer.update(1, 0L);
    }

    public void update(MutableAggregationBuffer mutableAggregationBuffer, Row row) {
        long timestamp = mutableAggregationBuffer.getLong(0);
        long count = mutableAggregationBuffer.getLong(1);
        long event_time = row.getLong(1);
        int interval = row.getInt(2);
        if (event_time > timestamp + interval) {
            timestamp = event_time - event_time % interval;
            count = 0;
        }
        if (row.getBoolean(0)) {
            count++;
        }
        mutableAggregationBuffer.update(0, timestamp);
        mutableAggregationBuffer.update(1, count);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void merge(MutableAggregationBuffer mutableAggregationBuffer, Row row) {

    }

    @Override
    public Object evaluate(Row row) {
        return row.getLong(1);
    }
}
```

Then I sumbit a sql like:

```sql
select timestamp, id, MyCount(true, timestamp, 10) over(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) as count from xxx.xxx
```

the result is:

```
timestamp    id     count
1642760594    0        1
1642760596    0        2
1642760599    0        3
1642760610    0        2 --duplicate
1642760610    0        2
1642760613    0        3
1642760594    1        1
1642760597    1        2
1642760600    1        1
1642760603    1        2
1642760606    1        4 --duplicate
1642760606    1        4
1642760608    1        5
```

When the timestamp is repeated, I get 1,2,4,4,5 instead of 1,2,3,4,5
How to fix it？

And another requestion is that when to execute the merge method of udaf? I empty implement it but it runs normally. I try to add the log in the method but I haven't seen this log. Is it really necessary？

---

There is a similar question: [Apache Spark SQL UDAF over window showing odd behaviour with duplicate input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554974/apache-spark-sql-udaf-over-window-showing-odd-behaviour-with-duplicate-input)

---

However, row_number() does not have such a problem. row_number() is a hive udaf, then I try to create a hive udaf. But I also have the problem...[Why hive udaf row_number() terminate() returns 'ArrayList'? I create my udaf row_number2() by copying its code then I got list return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030857/why-hive-udaf-row-number-terminate-returns-arraylistintwritable-i-creat)

Comment: If that is all you need maybe you can use `window()` function instead of creating your own UDAF? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#window-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: But I have a condition when it is true, the result accumulates one, and when it is false, the result is same as last time. How to use window() function to implement it?

Comment: not sure I follow -- where is this condition in your question?

Comment: sorry i didn't describe clearly. Please see the code that the function's 1st param is the condition. The count++ only when the condition is true, otherwise, it return the last count value.

Comment: This is a classic https://xyproblem.info/. Do not attempt to force a solution, simply describe what is the requested output for a given input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved it by spark aggregateWindowFunction:

```scala
case class Count(condition: Expression) extends AggregateWindowFunction with Logging {

  override def prettyName: String = "myCount"

  override def dataType: DataType = LongType

  override def children: Seq[Expression] = Seq(condition)

  private val zero = Literal(0L)
  private val one = Literal(1L)

  private val count = AttributeReference("count", LongType, nullable = false)()

  private val increaseCount = If(condition, Add(count, one), count)

  override val initialValues: Seq[Expression] = zero :: Nil
  override val updateExpressions: Seq[Expression] = increaseCount :: Nil
  override val evaluateExpression: Expression = count

  override val aggBufferAttributes: Seq[AttributeReference] = count :: Nil
```

Then use spark_session.functionRegistry.registerFunction to register it.

```sql
"select myCount(true) over(partition by window(timestamp, '10 seconds'), id order by timestamp) as count from xxx"
```